# How to start a maximum of X threads ? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Hello i have the following question:

My goal is to submit an email to an online list. The way that I have it right now starts as many threads as emails in my 01.csv file but i want it to have a maximum of 10 threads and once 1 thread is done continue with the next one but never goes above 10 active threads.

This is my main function which gets the emails from csv and start the target function:

```
def main():
    get_emails()

    log("Starting tasks", "yellow")

    # Loop through users
    for user in users:
        # Start thread for each user

        # Random timer so everyone doesn't request at the same time
        #timer = random.randint(0, 100)/100
        #time.sleep(timer)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=targetfunc, args=(users[user], ))
        thread.start()


        
    #os.system("clear")

    log("Task started successfully!", "success")
```

This is the function to get the mails :

```
def get_emails():
global users


with open("./emails.csv", "r") as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        if i == 0:
            data_titles = d
        else:
            users[d[0]] = {}

            for title in data_titles:
                users[d[0]][title] = d[data_titles.index(title)]
```

And here is the targetfunc the one thats does the email submit:

```
def targetfunc(data):
    global users_done
    global successCount
    #session = requests.session()


    email = data["EMAIL"]
...
...
...
```

How would i turn this code into one that only runs 5 threads at a time?

Comment: Start 10 threads, have them all wait on a producer-consumer queue in a loop.  Push all the addresses etc to the queue.  Watch as the 10 threads process all the emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement your own queue and have 10 threads started, that each pull from the queue, or - for this simple task - you could also use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) with a given number of workers.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as ex:
    for user in users:
        ex.submit(targetfunc, (users[user], ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I tried it but when i start the script nothing happens

Comment: "Nothing happens" is hard to debug. ;) I used `targetfunc` and arg syntax as in your question - which I could not test fully. However, when I do a minimal example with 
`for entry in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:` and `ex.submit(print, entry)` I get the strings prined as expected. Can you try that? If that works the issue must be elsewhere. ;)